# How to build dotnet core on self hosted ubuntu container agent?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I have a self hosted container using ubuntu.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# To make it easier for build and release pipelines to run apt-get,
# configure apt to not require confirmation (assume the -y argument by default)
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    jq \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    libcurl4 \
    libicu60 \
    libunwind8 \
    netcat \
    libssl1.0 \
    zip \
    unzip \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -LsS https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

This runs and active on azure platform. I am running an angular build pipeline on this agent and runs successfully.

But when I created a dotnet core project and build on this agent, it throws exceptions.

If I use following:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: PCDOCKER

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  projectName: vitrin-api

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'my-vsts-feed' # A series of numbers and letters

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

The error is at DotNetCoreCLI@2 step:

```
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'dotnet'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

If I use

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

instead of DotNetCoreCLI@2, it throws exception to not found "**mono**"

How can I build my dotnet application on my self hosted container?

Answer (score 1):

To build a .NET Core application, .NET SDK needs to be present on the system. .NET SDK includes all the necessary components required to build and run the application.

### To fix this issue, install .NET SDK on your Ubuntu container

Before you install .NET, run the following commands to add the Microsoft package signing key to your list of trusted keys and add the package repository.

Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/21.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Now, install .NET SDK

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

Checkout this for more detail - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2110-

Comment: I am using docker file to build container. Should I type that commands in container docker file?

Comment: I guess yes... because eventually we will need dotnet SDK to build .net core apps. It is a prerequisite.

Comment: Added all commands dockerfile of container but same error.